# Spectral radius of a compact operator and convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a compact operator such that the spectral radius $\rho(T)<1$
does it then follow that $||T^n|| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the spectral radius formula
$$
\rho(T) = \lim \|T^n\|^{1/n}
$$
Fix $\delta > 0$. Suppose $\rho(T) < 1$, then there is $1 > \epsilon > 0$, and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
n \geq n_0 \Rightarrow \|T^n\|^{1/n} < (1-\epsilon)
$$
Or equivalently,
$$
\|T^n\| < (1-\epsilon)^n \quad\forall n\geq n_0
$$
Since $(1-\epsilon) < 1$, there is $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
(1-\epsilon)^n < \delta \quad\forall n \geq n_1
$$
Hence, for all $n\geq \max\{n_0,n_1\}$, it follows that
$$
\|T^n\| < \delta
$$
Hence, $\lim \|T^n\| = 0$

Comment: Shouldn't it be noted that $\epsilon$ is small?

Comment: @user108307 : Edited.